# How do you get "I Killed Them All" in Titanfall?

Tags: achievements, titanfall

In Titanfall there is an achievement:

> **I Killed Them All**
>
> Killed all pilots during the evacuation single-handedly

This seems almost impossible:

- None of your team mates can get any of the other team.
- All of the other team need to run for the evac ship (or at lease all be close together any on the far end of the map are unlikely to get taken out by the same person).
- None (or only 1) of the other team can be in titans (getting even one down can take the whole evac time).
- Nobody rage quits? I'm not certain on this, but I think disconnects can't count as your kill.

This seems to be a perfect storm that almost never happens - it seems harder the longer the game is out as the reward for a successful evac is less than most players will get for getting on with some challenges on the far side of the map.

Any ways to get this achievement (without boosting)?

Comment: FWIW, I always try for a successful evac. It's the principle of the thing. Brings back memories of escaping a doomed Titan in 2142....except in reverse.

Answer (score 3):

This achievement really boils down to how lucky you are. 
There are quite a few ways you can earn it, but the "easiest" being destroy the dropship once their whole team has boarded (easier said than done, but yeah).

Without a pre-made team 'agreeing' to let/help you get the achievement it is near impossible to set anything up. If you are trying to get it in a public match however I would say make it to the evac point ***first*** and camp it as best you can. Most of the time everyone will head to the dropship for the final fight instead of wandering aimlessy(although I'm guilty of wandering...).

This achievement does count if you are the loser and kill them all. So Counter-Camping could also benefit you. Most of the time they won't expect you fight back. Tossing C4/grenades around is a good way to try and flush out the campers and then you can pick off the ones camping from a distance

If **ANY** piloted Titans are in play... just don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this, then got it again in quick succession:

Both times I was very lucky. The first time:

- I was equipped with a chain gun.
- Every other titan on my team was carrying either plasma rifles, triple threats or quad rockets.
- We'd cleared out every enemy titan.
- We were in Swamplands, where you can look down on one of the evac points.
- Everyone on the enemy team ran for the exit.
- I mowed them down as they arrived.

The second time I got insanely lucky with a well times nuclear explosion just under the drop ship as everyone ran for it.

This 'perfect storm' tool place for me after maybe 100 hours of play time.

Comment: told you in the first part of my answer, heh. It's pretty much entirely based on luck.